# adding word wrap for D3.js tree chart labels

Tags: d3.js, treechart

I'm new to **D3.js** and want to wrap long labels in the [tree chart](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092)

Can someone guide me how to do this?

Here is what I've tried:

```
var insertLinebreaks = function (t, d, width) {
    var el = d3.select(t);
    var p = d3.select(t.parentNode);
    p.append("foreignObject")
        .attr('x', -width/2)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", 200)
      .append("xhtml:p")
        .attr('style','word-wrap: break-word; text-align:center;')
        .html(d);    

    el.remove();
};

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.selectAll('text')
    .each(function(d,i){ insertLinebreaks(this, d, 10 ); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work.
Thanks to [this sample](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321)

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy"))/2,
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [' ' + word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

var json = 
{
    "name": "Base",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "I have a very long sentence that needs to be broken up",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Section 1",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Section 2",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Either you break this up or one of us is in deep trouble",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Section 1",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Section 2",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var width = 700;
var height = 650;
var maxLabel = 150;
var duration = 500;
var radius = 5;
    
var i = 0;
var root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + maxLabel + ",0)");

root = json;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

root.children.forEach(collapse);

function update(source) 
{
    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
    var links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * maxLabel; });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d){ 
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i); 
        });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
        .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 0)
        .style("fill", function(d){ 
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "white"; 
        });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d){ 
            var spacing = computeRadius(d) + 5;
            return d.children || d._children ? -spacing : spacing; 
        })
        .attr("dy", "3")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d){ return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function(d){ return d.name; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d){ return computeRadius(d); })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1);
    nodeUpdate.select("text").call(wrap, 200); // <++++++++++ wrap it!
    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle").attr("r", 0);
    nodeExit.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d){ return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d){
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d){
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d){
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

function computeRadius(d)
{
    if(d.children || d._children) return radius + (radius * nbEndNodes(d) / 10);
    else return radius;
}

function nbEndNodes(n)
{
    nb = 0;    
    if(n.children){
        n.children.forEach(function(c){ 
            nb += nbEndNodes(c); 
        });
    }
    else if(n._children){
        n._children.forEach(function(c){ 
            nb += nbEndNodes(c); 
        });
    }
    else nb++;
    
    return nb;
}

function click(d)
{
    if (d.children){
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } 
    else{
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}

function collapse(d){
    if (d.children){
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

update(root);
```

Comment: I don't know if anyone will see this, but I have tried this and it chops off the first 3 characters of my text.  Any idea why?  I have the same exact code.

Comment: @ChileAddict-Intel I have put the complete html/javascript which can be viewed. I think there was a tiny bug there that I fixed. Cheers

Comment: Interesting - I tried out the change and it still chops of the first three characters.  I did find a work-around hack though, so I'm good.

Answer (score 0):

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Tree Example</title>

    <style>
    
    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
    
<script>
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy"))/2,
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");

    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [' ' + word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

var json = 
{
    "name": "Base",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "I have a very long sentence that needs to be broken up",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Section 1",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Section 2",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Either you break this up or one of us is in deep trouble",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Section 1",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Section 2",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var width = 700;
var height = 650;
var maxLabel = 150;
var duration = 500;
var radius = 5;

var i = 0;
var root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + maxLabel + ",0)");

root = json;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

root.children.forEach(collapse);

function update(source) 
{
    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
    var links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * maxLabel; });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d){ 
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i); 
        });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
        .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 0)
        .style("fill", function(d){ 
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "white"; 
        });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d){ 
            var spacing = computeRadius(d) + 5;
            return d.children || d._children ? -spacing : spacing; 
        })
        .attr("dy", "3")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d){ return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function(d){ return d.name; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d){ return computeRadius(d); })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1);
    nodeUpdate.select("text").call(wrap, 200); // <++++++++++ wrap it!
    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle").attr("r", 0);
    nodeExit.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d){ return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d){
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d){
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d){
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

function computeRadius(d)
{
    if(d.children || d._children) return radius + (radius * nbEndNodes(d) / 10);
    else return radius;
}

function nbEndNodes(n)
{
    nb = 0;    
    if(n.children){
        n.children.forEach(function(c){ 
            nb += nbEndNodes(c); 
        });
    }
    else if(n._children){
        n._children.forEach(function(c){ 
            nb += nbEndNodes(c); 
        });
    }
    else nb++;

    return nb;
}

function click(d)
{
    if (d.children){
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } 
    else{
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}

function collapse(d){
    if (d.children){
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

update(root);

</script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```